# iOS 10 notification extension: can I change the action button text?

Tags: ios, ios10, unnotificationattachment

I've been playing around a little with the `UNNotificationContentExtension` framework to display a custom view inside a notification. So far, so good - got it rendering, and then altering content when a user taps on an action button.

But the one thing I don't seem to be able to do is change the text in the action buttons - not necessarily surprising given that it is defined in a `UNNotificationAction` I have to declare beforehand, but I'm wondering if anyone has had any luck in finding a way to change the button text?